# Rails, Devise: unknown attribute 'password' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model, attributes

I have been using the [devise-two-factor](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor) gem on my [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) user model. When I try to remove the gem from the model, I get the following error when creating a user record:

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'password' for User.
>   c:/test_app/db/seeds.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
>   bin/rails:4:in`require'
>   bin/rails:4:in `'

---

Here is my previous devise integration in my model:

```
devise :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
        :omniauthable,
        :invitable,
        :two_factor_authenticatable, :two_factor_backupable,
        :otp_secret_encryption_key => Settings.devise.two_factor.key,
        :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
```

And my current integration:

```
devise :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
        :omniauthable,
        :invitable,
        :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
```

My seed:

```
demo_user = User.create(email: 'demo@example.com', first_name: 'demo', last_name: 'account', password: '12345678', username: 'demo')
demo_user.encrypted_password
demo_user.skip_confirmation!
```

---

How does deleting these two lines affect the `password` attribute of the model? That code snippet is the only thing I've changed.

Comment: Can you add your `db/seeds.rb` file to the question?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I added it to the markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`two_factor_authenticatable` is the explanation: Devise can only work with passwords if your model has some form of `:authenticatable`. 
Try adding `:database_authenticatable` instead and Devise should be able to assign the password correctly.

If that doesn't help, see the Devise documentation for more: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview#using-omniauth-without-other-authentications

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> demo_user = User.create(email: 'demo@example.com', first_name: 'demo',
>                         last_name: 'account', password: '12345678',
>                         username: 'demo')
> ```

There's your problem. You're trying to set a `password` attribute on a new `User`, but the Devise `User` model doesn't have a `password` attribute.

Devise users have an `encrypted_password` attribute, but that gets generated by Devise when a user is created and you probably shouldn't try to fill it on your own. It's not a method that encrypts a `password` attribute.

Comment: I don't think this is intended, as my devise sign up form with the default `password` input is also failing.

Comment: I still don't know why `password` depends on `two-factor`. With the gem everything works fine.

Comment: `User.create(email: '...', password: '12341234', password_confirmation: '12341234')` will save an encrypted password with Devise.